# Having problems with a reactive list in Svelte

Tags: reactive-programming, svelte

I am new to Svelte and I am stuck with a list that is not reacting to user input.

Here is my situation simplified:

- Parent component (App.svelte) shows a list of Objects
- Child component provides Input-Elements to change values of the list.

Problem: When I change the values in the Input Element, the list in App.svelte won't update.

Code:

App.svelte

```
<script>
    import Nested from './Nested.svelte';
    
    let customers=[{
        id:1,
        name: "Smith"
    },{
        id:2,
        name: "Foo"
    },{
        id:3,
        name: "Bar"
    }]
</script>

{#each customers as customer (customer.id)}
    <p>{customer.name}</p>
{/each}

<Nested {customers}/>
```

Nested.svelte:

```
<script>
    export let customers;
</script>

{#each customers as customer (customer.id)}
    <p><input bind:value={customer.name} /></p>
{/each}
```

Link to REPL: https://svelte.dev/repl/fb22de4557744d8b8f4410f21402efca?version=3.32.3

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use two way binding for the component: <Nested bind:customers={customers}/>

Answer (score 2):

Svelte won't automatically update a prop in the parent when you update it in the child. You will need to opt-in to this two-way binding using the [bind directive](https://svelte.dev/docs#bind_component_property). It works similarly to the [value binding](https://svelte.dev/docs#bind_element_property) you used on the `<input>`.

```html
{#each customers as customer (customer.id)}
    <p>{customer.name}</p>
{/each}

<Nested bind:customers/>
```